# How to detect if a window is visible on modern multi monitor systems

Tags: c#, winforms

How do I detect if window is not visible to the user and then move it to a position that is visible to allow the user to size it to their liking.

The problem:-
I have a program that save the position and size of the form this works perfectly.
Unfortunately, many users now have multiple screen graphics cards that can be switched between duplicate and extended.

Therefore, if the user closes the form (the program saves where it was) and the user switches his system to say extended from duplicate then opens the program.
 The program form is now not visible because it has moved off the limits of the current screen system :(
The user can see it running on the task bar. However clicking the icon only gives a brief flash of minimising or maximising the program and right clicking only has the option to close.

I need to trap for not visible to the user and then auto resize to any active window. The user can then resize/move as they see fit.

I would welcome any ideas/pointers

Comment: Do you have custom logic for saving the screen position of your window?

Comment: Don't you want the operating system to handle that?

Comment: @Jodrell, would the OS remember the position of windows that are subordinate to the main application window?

Comment: Do you have custom logic for saving the screen position of your window? – Phil Gan. Yes I do, that is how the system knows where to locate its self. It all goes wrong if the user swaps his/her style extended or duplicate

Comment: @Jodrell, seems like there's a reason he needs this functionality. Try thinking outside of the box.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[This answer](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/winforms/thread/cc586cd9-97a6-4b3b-866f-1c1b9b73b141) was provided for the same question on the MSDN forums - essentially, it's a quick check of the bounds of the screen, and checks to see if the program is within those bounds. If not, it moves it to `0, 0`:

```
using System.Windows.Forms; 

class Form1 : Form {
    protected void EnsureVisible() {
        foreach (Screen scrn in Screen.AllScreens) {
        // You may prefer Intersects(), rather than Contains()
            if (scrn.Bounds.Contains(this.Bounds)) {
              return;
            }
        }
        this.Location = new Point( 0, 0 );
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm going to try out this idea first; because it has sample code :)

Comment: Use Screen.FromRectangle() instead.

Comment: Thank you all. I have now got the program working with the code supplied by Jared Harley.

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of the [AllScreens](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.screen.allscreens.aspx) property to get a list of all the screens connected to the computer. Using that, you can check the bounding boxes of each screen and test if your window lies outside all of them. If so, then reset the position.

And Jared Harley beat me to it, while I was typing this.